# Changing the engine to InnoDB from MyISAM is not working

Tags: innodb, myisam, mysql

I am trying to change the table engine from MyISAM to INNODB. I am using the

> `alter table tablename ENGINE=INNODB`

command. I am not getting any errors or warnings on the mysql side. I also commented the

> skip-innodb

line in my.cnf file. So when I do a

> show variables like 'have-innodb%'

it gives me a "YES". Also just to be on the safe side, I also deleted my ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 and restarted my mysql server.

But it still does not change the engine. I also did a show engines, and it shows innodb as one of the available engines.

Also these tables are full of data and have around 5000 rows, so is changing the engine type when a table has data, would that be the problem??

What could the missing link be??

Comment: Have you run a `show create table table_name` to verify that it hasn't changed?

Comment: Well I do a show table status where name='tablename'. And shows myisam

Comment: This could be a MySQL bug, what version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to restart the server?  If so, the error log will tell you if it had problems initialising the InnoDB engine.
Is this the first InnoDB table in your db?  If so, you may have forgotten to create your ibdata files.
Does the table use fulltext indexing or other InnoDB-incompatible features?

Comment: Nic, could you help me out with finding the error log. I tried looking for it in /var/lib/mysql, but I did not find it there. I am on fedora, is there another location for storing mysql error logs?

Comment: Ok I did find the log file, it says the InnoDB server started well

Comment: In your variables, look for `datadir`, `innodb-data-home-dir`, `innodb-data-file-path`: those will help you find your ibdata file (which holds InnoDB tables).